# How to get the list of adjacent items with the same name only

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that looks like this :

```
public static void main {
   int itemToBeSearched = 4;

   List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "name2" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 4, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 5, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 6, Name = "name3" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 7, Name = "name1" });

    //I need help in getting a return here
    var subList = GetAdjacentList(list, itemToBeSearched);
}

public List<Item> GetAdjacentList(List list, int itemToBeSearched)
{
    //Need help with the logic or linq here that would give a return such as
    return List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 4, Name = "name1" });
        list.Add(new Item { Id = 5, Name = "name1" });
}
```

And the desired output should be: a sublist out of this that only contains `Item2, Item3` and `Item4`.

I only wanted a return of a sublist that only contains `Item3, Item4` and `Item5` because they are ***adjacent*** to each other with the ***same name which is `name1`***.

`Item1` and `Item7` are not included even though they have the name as `name1` because it isn't close to the adjacent group.

Can someone help me solve this using Linq or otherwise?

Comment: Please provide actual code for your list.

Comment: @John I have added the code on my list. Thanks.

Comment: Is the Id unique?

Comment: @John Yes, the Id is unique. I have added some more code for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a simpler way of doing it, but I came up with this. It doesn't use any LINQ, but it does maintain the order of the list items (assuming that's important).

```
public static List<Item> GetAdjacentList(List<Item> list, int itemToBeSearched)
{
    List<Item> result = new List<Item>();
    // find the index of the item we're searching for
    int itemIdx = list.FindIndex(i => i.Id == itemToBeSearched);
    if (itemIdx == -1)
    {
        return result; // not found, return empty list
    }

    // store the item for comparisons
    Item item = list[itemIdx];

    // loop backwards starting from the current item ann going to the 0th element
    for (int i = itemIdx; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        // if this item is the search item, or the name matches, add it to the list
        if (i == itemIdx || list[i].Name == item.Name)
        {
            result.Add(list[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            // exit the loop as we've run out of items with the same name
            break;
        }
    }

    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        result.Reverse(); // we've added items in reverse order, so reverse the list
    }

    // loop through all the items from the next item to the end of the list
    for (int i = itemIdx + 1; i < list.Count; ++i)
    {
        // if the name matches add it to the result list
        if (list[i].Name == item.Name)
        {
            result.Add(list[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            // we've reached the end of matching names so break
            break;
        }
    }
    // return the result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Except if I put the itemToBeSearched to be 1. The list returns empty.

Comment: I think I've fixed it, though I'm not at my pc to test it. I changed i > 0 to i >= 0

Comment: Yup, I can see it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what happens when there are two groups of consecutive Ids. For example,

[image]

**Case 1** : Retrieve as two separate groups

Assuming you could like to retrieve both islands of groups as separate collections, you could modify the method as following.

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> GetAdjacentList(List<Item> list, int itemToBeSearched)
{
    var nameToBeSearched = list.First(x=>x.Id==itemToBeSearched).Name;
    return list.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals(nameToBeSearched))
                .GroupWhile((x, y) => y.Id - x.Id == 1)
                .Where(x=>x.Count()>1);
}
```

Where `GroupWhile` is defined as

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T,T,bool> condition)
    {
        T prev = seq.First();
        List<T> list = new List<T>() { prev };
    
        foreach(T item in seq.Skip(1))
        {
            if(condition(prev,item)==false)
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }
            list.Add(item);
            prev = item;
        }
    
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

*Output*

[image]

**Case 2** : Retrieve as a single merged group

In case you want to the two island groups to be merged as one, then you could modify the above method as

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAdjacentList(List<Item> list, int itemToBeSearched)
{
    var nameToBeSearched = list.First(x=>x.Id==itemToBeSearched).Name;
    return list.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals(nameToBeSearched))
                .GroupWhile((x, y) => y.Id - x.Id == 1)
                .Where(x=>x.Count()>1).SelectMany(x=>x);
}
```

*Output*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this awesome reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple backward and forward loops to find the adjacent items of a specific name within a given range and return a `List<Item>` with the same order of the items:

```cs
public List<Item> GetAdjacentList(List<Item> list, int itemToBeSearched, int range)
{
    var result = new List<Item>();
    var tar = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == itemToBeSearched);

    if (tar == null) return result;

    var indx = list.IndexOf(tar);
            
    for (var i = indx - 1; i >= (indx - range); i--)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && list[i].Name.Equals(tar.Name, 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            result.Insert(0, list[i]);
        else
            break;
    }

    result.Add(list[indx]);

    for (var i = indx + 1; i <= (indx + range) ; i++)
    {
        if (i < list.Count() && list[i].Name.Equals(tar.Name, 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            result.Add(list[i]);
        else
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The outputs of the given `List<Item>` example (`rang = 1`):

```
The adjacent items of ID 1 => 1       (name1)
The adjacent items of ID 2 => 2       (name2)
The adjacent items of ID 3 => 3, 4    (name1)
The adjacent items of ID 4 => 3, 4, 5 (name1)
The adjacent items of ID 5 => 4, 5    (name1)
The adjacent items of ID 6 => 6       (name3)
The adjacent items of ID 7 => 7       (name1)
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Does it only work with +1 and -1 ranges? Is it possible to make this range dynamic? For example if there are 4 adjacent items with the same name?

Comment: @PaulaKristin The new one does. Just pass the required range in the third parameter.